# Atlas of pathology / morbid anatomy. Is there any?

Tags: pathophysiology

Is there any atlas which have Human's fresh pathological gross specimen with their segmental cut-sections of different tissues? Why fresh! the reason is after embalming any tissues, organs changes into different color, consistency etc so it  becomes hard to compare with the gross normal organs. So that it would be more realistic study.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Gross anatomy is another way to term what you're saying. There are likely histology and pathology textbooks as well, which may get you closer to the "cut-sections" you refer to.  We don't usually provide textbook advice but perhaps someone has some suggestions on where to look